# Java Bean Utils to call all setters with non String types

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am trying to call all setter method for my bean using a hashmap. The key is the property name and the value is the actual value i need to set by calling setters. Follwoing code works perfectly for string proerties but fails on non string properties like int,double etc.

```
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : settings.entrySet()){
        try{
                    key = entry.getKey();
                    PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, key, entry.getValue());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LOGGER.debug("failed...."+ex.getMessage());     
        }
    }
```

The above code throws exception for non String fields like int / double etc

```
failed....Cannot invoke setter on bean class - argument type mismatch - had objects of type "java.lang.String" but expected signature "int"

failed....Cannot invoke setter on bean class - argument type mismatch - had objects of type "java.lang.String" but expected signature "double"
```

The question is: How to avoid this excepition, how to call setter successfully without having this exception.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Edited with question details. Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with your code is that your Map.Entry is been loaded as a two String tuple, so when passing the value to setProperty is a String what you are sending, even when the method expects an int or float or whatever.

Have not tested this, but you can give it a try

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : settings.entrySet()){
    try{
                key = entry.getKey();
                Class propertyClass = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(bean, key).getPropertyType();
                if (propertyClass.getName().equals('Integer')) {
                    PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, key, Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue()));
                } // and so with other types.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LOGGER.debug("failed...."+ex.getMessage());     
    }
}
```